# HttpContext.Current Request "Not Available" while running "Local IIS Web Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was trying to work with the http context (with the help of Httpcontext.current) in the application_start event in global.asax then you will receive an Error:- HttpContext.Current Request is not available in this context.

The problem can easily be worked with a workaround by using a static constructor, which is fired when the object is accessed first. We can keep a flag in the Application_Beginrequest event and easily determine the request that initialized the application.

But in this case it gets created at every request, which is not required for me. I want to create or access Httpcontext.current once

My Code Is as Follows :-

```
        `//var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        //var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context) ?? new RouteData();
        //var requestContext = new RequestContext(context, routeData);
        //var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
        //var url = urlHelper.Action("Home", "Index");

        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()));
        if (urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {

        }
        //if (((requestContext.HttpContext).Request).IsLocal)
        //{

        //}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `HttpContext` nor `HttpRequest` instance in `App_Start` in integrated mode. You must work around this. If you really need to do something on first request, then register new `BeginRequest` handler in your global.asax and then unregister it when you are done.